# Dreamweaver multiple checkbox selection then insert to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, checkbox, insert, dreamweaver

I have an order form and the products are in checkboxes. The selected items should be inserted to a database column. I'm not very good in coding yet so it would be great if you showed me an example. Thank you.

Here's my table:

```
<form name="form" method="POST">
    <table width="623" height="283" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="146">Name:</td>
<td width="266"><label for="name"></label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact No:</td>
<td><label for="contactno"></label>
  <input type="text" name="contactno" id="contactno" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><label for="address"></label>
  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="31">Select Items:</td>
<td>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup[]" value="sample one" id="CheckboxGroup_0" />
      Checkbox</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup[]" value="sample two" id="CheckboxGroup_1" />
      Sample</label>
    <br />
    <br />
</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Payment Option:</td>
<td>
  <label for="pay_option"></label>
  <select name="pay_option" id="pay_option">
    <option value="Counter">Counter</option>
    <option value="BDO">BDO</option>
    <option value="Smart Money">Smart Money</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Claiming Option:</td>
<td>
  <label for="claim_option"></label>
  <select name="claim_option" id="claim_option">
    <option value="Pick-up">Pick-up</option>
    <option value="Shipping">Shipping</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Basically, whatever the user selects, should be inserted to a db column upon clicking the submit button. I don't know the PHP script for it.I use dreamweaver and mysql workbench

PHP

the code you gave me is at the very bottom. the rest are generated by DW when i did the insert record gui

```
<?php require_once('Connections/MCC.php'); ?>

<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO order_form (name, address, contact_no, payment_option, claim_option, orders) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['address'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['contactno'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['pay_option'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['claim_option'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['CheckboxGroup[]']) ? "true" : "", "defined","'Y'","'N'"));

mysql_select_db($database_MCC, $MCC);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $MCC) or die(mysql_error());
}

//-------added this---------
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $implode=implode(",",$_POST['CheckboxGroup']);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_form (orders) VALUES ('".$implode."')") ;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. In its current form your question is unanswerable, because it is too broad. Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27739373/edit) your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
$implode=implode(",",$_POST['CheckboxGroup']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_form (orders) VALUES ('".$implode."')") ;
}
?>

 <?php
 require_once('Connections/MCC.php');
 if(isset($_POST['button']))
 {
 $implode=implode(",",$_POST['CheckboxGroup']);
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_form (name, address, contact_no, payment_option,  claim_option, orders) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['address']."',  '".$_POST['contact_no']."', '".$_POST['payment_option']."', '".$_POST['claim_option']."',  '".$implode"')");
}
?>
```

Comment: still  getting N. i don't know anymore.maybe i placed the code in a wrong position. Do you know any tutorial for checkboxes to mysql?

Comment: wait i will give you output

Comment: Please check the code brother on 14th line what was the mistake...What ever the issue you are facing for that i have give the solution but you have problem with pasted code.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"')"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\MCC\orderform.php on line 14

Comment: check double & single cotes problem is there itself

Comment: How about if there's a select/drop-down beside each checkbox? i also want to insert those in 1 field,just like what you did here. i have a new question up please check that out.maybe you can help again

Comment: Can you place question what exactly you need here it is not clear for me

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value by the following two methods

1) you can serialize the array and store it in one column of a table (eg orders or products).
something like that

```
$orders = serialize($_POST['CheckboxGroup']);

insert into orders (products)values('".$orders."');
```

2)
or you can adopt the second option which will create the duplication .

```
foreach($_POST['CheckboxGroup'] as $val){
insert into orders (products)values('".$val."');
}
```

Note: it is just an example to show you the logic.you can make it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$implode=implode(",",$_POST['CheckboxGroup']);
insert into orders (products) values('".$implode."')
```

Comment: i first used the insert record using dreamweaver's gui for the other data in my form and inserted this at the top.

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
  $implode=implode(",",$_POST['CheckboxGroup']);
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_form (orders) VALUES ('".$implode."')") ;
   }

It only inserts N in the column. not the selected items.what did i do wrong?

Comment: check once datatype of orders field

Comment: what should be the datatype for that field?

Comment: type->varchar,length->255

Comment: still getting N. T___T